# How to solve the Android crash caused by ART?

Tags: android, dalvik

I got the crash when i launch a project on moto x pro on Android 5.0.2. How to solve it or how to avoid it ?

I also found a post [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78680), but have no conclusion.

```
--------- beginning of crash
12-16 16:16:26.300 F/libc    (23963): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 24030 (diastreamerdemo)
12-16 16:16:26.406 I/DEBUG   (13200): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
12-16 16:16:26.406 I/DEBUG   (13200): Build fingerprint: 'motorola/shamu_retcn/shamu_t:5.0.2/LXG22.67-7.1/2:user/release-keys'
12-16 16:16:26.406 I/DEBUG   (13200): Revision: 'p2b0'
12-16 16:16:26.406 I/DEBUG   (13200): ABI: 'arm'
12-16 16:16:26.406 I/DEBUG   (13200): pid: 23963, tid: 24030, name: diastreamerdemo  >>> com.jerikc.mediastreamerdemo <<<
12-16 16:16:26.406 I/DEBUG   (13200): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
12-16 16:16:26.467 I/DEBUG   (13200):     r0 00000058  r1 00000000  r2 00000006  r3 a34227b8
12-16 16:16:26.467 I/DEBUG   (13200):     r4 00000006  r5 b4f98800  r6 b4f98858  r7 00000001
12-16 16:16:26.467 I/DEBUG   (13200):     r8 00000090  r9 a2f09100  sl a3206418  fp 00000008
12-16 16:16:26.467 I/DEBUG   (13200):     ip a34227b8  sp a3422728  lr a2f09100  pc b4d046fa  cpsr 20020030
12-16 16:16:26.467 I/DEBUG   (13200):
12-16 16:16:26.467 I/DEBUG   (13200): backtrace:
12-16 16:16:26.468 I/DEBUG   (13200):     #00 pc 001156fa  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::allocator::RosAlloc::RefillRun(art::Thread*, unsigned int)+253)
12-16 16:16:26.468 I/DEBUG   (13200):     #01 pc 001158ff  /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::allocator::RosAlloc::AllocFromRun(art::Thread*, unsigned int, unsigned int*)+490)
12-16 16:16:26.468 I/DEBUG   (13200):     #02 pc 000cdef9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::mirror::Object* art::gc::Heap::AllocObject<true, art::mirror::Class::InitializeClassVisitor>(art::Thread*, art::mirror::Class*, unsigned int, art::mirror::Class::InitializeClassVisitor const&)+848)
12-16 16:16:26.468 I/DEBUG   (13200):     #03 pc 000ce297  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::AllocClass(art::Thread*, unsigned int)+54)
12-16 16:16:26.469 I/DEBUG   (13200):     #04 pc 000d7621  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ClassLinker::DefineClass(art::Thread*, char const*, unsigned int, art::Handle<art::mirror::ClassLoader>, art::DexFile const&, art::DexFile::ClassDef const&)+96)
12-16 16:16:26.469 I/DEBUG   (13200):     #05 pc 00203f1b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DexFile_defineClassNative(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jstring*, _jobject*, long long)+554)
12-16 16:16:26.469 I/DEBUG   (13200):     #06 pc 0001a9af  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
12-16 16:16:26.467 W/debuggerd(13200): type=1400 audit(0.0:10825): avc: denied { search } for uid=0 name="com.jerikc.mediastreamerdemo" dev="mmcblk0p41" ino=338061 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
12-16 16:16:26.467 W/debuggerd(13200): type=1400 audit(0.0:10826): avc: denied { search } for uid=0 name="com.jerikc.mediastreamerdemo" dev="mmcblk0p41" ino=338061 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```